# How to intercept request in Puppeteer before current page is left?

Tags: puppeteer

### Usecase:

We need to capture all outbound routes from a page. Some of them may not be implemented using link elements `<a src="...">` but via some javascript code or as `GET`/`POST` forms.

### PhantomJS:

In Phantom we did this using `onNavigationRequested` callback. We simply clicked at all the elements defined by some selector and used `onNavigationRequested` to capture the target url and possibly method or POST data in a case of form and then canceled that navigation event.

### Puppeteer:

I tried request interception but at the moment request gets intercepted the current page is already lost so I would have to go back.

---

Is there a way how to capture the navigation event when the browser is still at the page that triggered the event and to stop it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

You can do the following.

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
  if (request.resourceType() === 'image')
    request.abort();
  else
    request.continue();
});
```

Example here:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/block-images.js

Available resource types are listed here:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestresourcetype

Answer (score 8):

So I finally discovered the solution that doesn't require browser extension and therefore works in a headless mode:

Thx to this guy: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/823#issuecomment-467408640

```
page.on('request', req => {
  if (req.isNavigationRequest() && req.frame() === page.mainFrame() && req.url() !== url) {
    // no redirect chain means the navigation is caused by setting `location.href`
    req.respond(req.redirectChain().length
      ? { body: '' } // prevent 301/302 redirect
      : { status: 204 } // prevent navigation by js
    )
  } else {
    req.continue()
  }
})
```

EDIT: We have added helper function to Apify SDK that implements this - https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteer#puppeteer.enqueueLinksByClickingElements

Here is whole source code:

https://github.com/apifytech/apify-js/blob/master/src/enqueue_links/click_elements.js

It's slightly more complicated as it does not only need to intercept requests but additionally also catch newly opened windows, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problems.Puppeteer doesn't support the feature now, actually it's chrome devtool that doesn't support it. But I found another way to solve it, using **chrome extension**. Related issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/823

The author of the issue shared a solution
 here. https://gist.github.com/GuilloOme/2bd651e5154407d2d2165278d5cd7cdb

As the [doc](https://crxdoc-zh.appspot.com/extensions/webRequest) says, we can use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` to intercept all request from the page and block it if you wanna do.

Don't forget to add the following command to the puppeteer launch options:

`--load-extension=./your_ext/ --disable-extensions-except=./your_ext/`

Answer (score 1):

`page.setRequestInterception(true);` The documentation has a really thorough example here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue.
Make sure to add some logic like in the example (and below) they avoid image requests. You would capture it and then abort each request.

```
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
     if (interceptedRequest.url.endsWith('.png') || 
                              interceptedRequest.url.endsWith('.jpg'))
         interceptedRequest.abort();
     else
         interceptedRequest.continue();
});
```